# How to make the camera move in the direction of the rotation?

Tags: java, opengl, camera, jogl

How can I make the camera move in the direction of the rotation? How do I calculate the position of the camera to follow the rotation? 
This is my code:

```
import javax.media.opengl.*;
import javax.media.opengl.awt.*;
import com.sun.opengl.util.*;
import com.sun.opengl.util.gl2.GLUT;
import javax.media.opengl.glu.*;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Rotation2 extends JFrame implements GLEventListener, KeyListener
{
    GLCanvas canvas = null;
    Animator an;

    public Rotation2()
    {   
        canvas=new GLCanvas();
        an=new Animator(canvas);
        add(canvas);
        canvas.addGLEventListener(this);
        canvas.addKeyListener(this);
        setSize(1280,900);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        an.start();
        requestFocus();

    }
    float xPosition = 0;
    float zPosition = 0;

    float red = 0;
    float green = 0;
    float blue = 1;


    public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable)
    {
        GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
        GLU glu = new GLU();
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        double w = drawable.getWidth();
        double h = drawable.getHeight();
        double aspect = w/h;
        glu.gluPerspective(60.0, aspect, 2.0, 20.0);

    }
    double zRot = 0;
    double xRot = 0;

    public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable)
    {
        GL2 gl=drawable.getGL().getGL2();
        GLU glu = new GLU();
        GLUT glut = new GLUT();

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glClearColor(0f,0f,0f,0f);
        //xPosition+=0.005;
        //zPosition+=0.005;
        gl.glRotated(zRot, 0, 1, 0);
        gl.glRotated(xRot, 1, 0, 0);
        glu.gluLookAt(xPosition, 0, zPosition,
                      xPosition, 0, (zPosition+20),
                      0, 1, 0);

        gl.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        red = 0.0f;
        green = 0.0f;
        blue = 0.9f;
        gl.glColor3f(red, green, blue);
//transforming the place the next shape
//will be drawn.
        gl.glTranslated(2, 0, 2);
//We use wire here because default
//lighting is not good enough to
//use when rendering the solid version
        glut.glutWireIcosahedron();
//more shapes to navigate through
        gl.glTranslated(-4, 0, 0);
        glut.glutWireIcosahedron();
        red = 0.0f;
        green = 0.9f;
        blue = 0.1f;
        gl.glColor3f(red, green, blue);
        gl.glTranslated(4, 0, 4);
        glut.glutWireIcosahedron();
        gl.glTranslated(-4, 0, 0);
        glut.glutWireIcosahedron();
        red = 0.9f;
        green = 0.0f;
        blue = 0.1f;
        gl.glColor3f(red, green, blue);
        gl.glTranslated(4, 0, 4);
        glut.glutWireIcosahedron();
        gl.glTranslated(-4, 0, 0);
        glut.glutWireIcosahedron();
        red = 0.9f;
        green = 0.0f;
        blue = 0.9f;
        gl.glColor3f(red, green, blue);
        gl.glTranslated(4, 0, 4);
        glut.glutWireIcosahedron();
        gl.glTranslated(-4, 0, 0);
        glut.glutWireIcosahedron();


    }

    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable,int x,int y,int width,int height)
    {}
    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable)
    {}


    public static void main(String[] ar)
    {

        new Rotation2();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            zPosition++;
        }
        else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            zPosition--;
        }
        else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            xPosition++;
        }
        else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            xPosition--;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            zRot+=5;
        }
        else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            zRot-=5;
        }
        else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            xRot-=5;
        }
        else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            xRot+=5;
        }
        canvas.repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }
}
```

p.s. You have to click the canvas for things to start working.

Comment: Instead of rotating your camera - why don't you just use transformations on your objects to change the point at which the camera is aimed and reflect the camera angles? You can do it with the various transformation matrices on your world.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to do that and by the sound of it doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for. 

I want to be able to move around objects like you would in FPS game.

Comment: Joey, there is no way other than you study and understand how things work, I am sorry but this is not stuff you can learn in 10 minutes

Comment: @elect I'm used to watching tutorials and learning things that way, I'm looking for pointers on how to model a FPS camera and I haven't studied any of the things related to it, I just know how to draw polygons and use transformation functions. The resources on JOGL are terrible! I can't find a good book or something like that :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

elect is right, you have to understand the basic concepts, you can't just tinker with no understanding of the notions on computer graphics. You can read the OpenGL Red Book, its code examples have been ported to JOGL and are available on Github [here](https://github.com/sgothel/jogl-demos/tree/master/src/redbook/src).

Those classes of my own first person shooter's very oldest alpha version show how to implement a camera except that you cannot look up or down:
[GameGLView](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/tuer/code/alpha/main/GameGLView.java)
[GameController](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/tuer/code/alpha/main/GameController.java)
[GameModel](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/tuer/code/alpha/main/GameModel.java)

P.S: I have to update it soon to make it work with JOGL 2.3.2 and later. It works with JOGL 2.3.1.

P.P.S: I updated the source code above to make it work with JOGL 2.3.2 yesterday (February, 4th, 2016).